# Showing that a set is open with metric

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Let $(A, d_1)$ and be a metric. Suppose $d_2: A \times A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined in this way:

For $a, b \in A$, $d_2(a, b) = \frac{d_1(a, b)}{1 + d_1(a, b)}$.

Show that $E \subset A$ is open with respect to $d_1 \iff E$ is open with respect to $d_2$.

My attempt:

I have replaced $a, b$ with $x, y$*

Proof.

Assume $E$ is open inside $(A, d_2)$. Then there is a $r > 0$ s.t. the open ball $B_2(x, r) = \{y \in A: d_2(x, y) < r\}$ is contained in $E$.

We need to show that for any $x \in E$, there is an $\rho > 0$ so that the open ball $B_1(x, \rho)  = \{y \in A: d_1(x, y) < \rho\}$ is contained in $E$.

Let $r < 1$ and set $\rho = \frac{r}{1 - r}$ then for $y \in B_1(x, \rho)$ we have

$$d_2(x, y) = \frac{d_1(x, y)}{1 + d_1(x, y)} < \frac{\rho}{1 + \rho} = r$$

So $y \in B_2(x, r)$ and so $B_1(x, \rho) \subset E$. Hence $E$ is open inside $(A, d_1)$.

The other way.

Assume $E$ is open inside $(A, d_1)$. Then there is a $\rho > 0$ s.t. the open ball $B_1(x, \rho) = \{y \in A: d_1(x, y) < \rho\}$ is contained in $E$.

We need to show that for any $x \in E$, there is an $r > 0$ so that the open ball $B_2(x, r)  = \{y \in A: d_2(x, y) < r\}$ is contained in $E$.

Set $r = \rho$ then for $y \in B_2(x, r)$ we have:

$$d_2(x, y) = \frac{d_1(x, y)}{1 + d_1(x, y)} \leq d_1(x, y) < \rho = r$$

So $y \in B_1(x, \rho)$ and $B_2(x, r) \subset E$. We may conclude $E$ is open inside $(A, d_2)$.

QED.

Is this proof correct? If not, can somebody explain where I went wrong. Any assistance much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nearly perfect.  Here's some quibbles (my changes in italic):

- Line 1, Then *for every $x\in E$* there is a $r>0$...
- Line 3, if $r\geq1$, $B_2(x,1/2)\subseteq B_2(x,r)$, which is why your logic suffices.
- Line 4, depending on your reader, it may not be clear that $\rho=\frac r{r-1}\implies r=\frac\rho{1+\rho}$, likewise for $\frac{d_1(x,y)}{1+d_1(x,y)}<\frac\rho{1+\rho}\implies d_1(x,y)<\rho$.  Only the algebra convinces me that the inequality is the direction it is.
- Line 7, Then *for every $x\in E$*..., I'm being pedantic.

Comment: Are you sure I did not make any logical error? I am having a gut feeling that something is missing.